# Client-server app turns off after logging

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, stack-overflow

In my C# server-client program I have following isue:

after logging to server with one of clients server automatically goes off with StackOverFlowException after connecting with IP and typing "LOGIN xxxxxxx".

[image: client]
[image: server]

Client code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SIKTcpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int Port = 3000;
        private static Socket _socket;
        private const int attemptsLimit = 2;
        private const int BufferSize = 2048;
        private static byte[] buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
        private static string _login;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Write ip adress");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var ipAdress = input.Length < 2 ? GetIpAdress() : input;
            if (input.Length < 2)
                Console.WriteLine(ipAdress);
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Connect(ipAdress);
            Console.WriteLine("Your login");
            try
            {
                if (input.Length < 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_login);
                    _socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_login));
                }
                while (true)
                {
                    var result = Console.ReadLine();
                    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
                    _socket.Send(bytes);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server was shut down.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        static void Connect(string ipAdress)
        {
            var attempts = 0;
            while (!_socket.Connected && attempts < attemptsLimit)
            {
                try
                {
                    ++attempts;
                    var result = _socket.BeginConnect(ipAdress, Port, EndConnect, null);
                    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            if(!_socket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to server");
                return;
            }
        }

        private static void EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                _socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
                if (_socket.Connected)
                {
                    _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _socket);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("End of connection attempt, fail to connect...");
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for server...");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cant connnect to server... " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                var socket = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    var received = socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
                    if (received > 0)
                    {
                        var data = new byte[received];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length);
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                            Console.Write("Server: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server was shut down.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Receive callback failed "+ ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static string GetIpAdress()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var r = random.Next(100000000);
            _login = "LOGIN " + r;
            using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
            {
                socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
                var endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                var localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
                return localIP;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIKTcpServer.Constants;
using SIKTcpServer.Models;
using SIKTcpServer.Models.Cards;

namespace SIKTcpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket _socket;
        private const int Port = 3000;
        private const int BufferSize = 2048;
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        private static List<Player> _players = new List<Player>();
        private static bool _gameStarted = false;
        private static List<Player> _playersInRound;
        private static readonly int[] _ids = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        private static List<AbstractCard> _turnCards;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            GatherPlayers();
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        private static void GatherPlayers()
        {
            //var a = LoadCards();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for players...");
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));
            _socket.Listen(0);
            _socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            while(_players.Count < 2) { }
            Console.WriteLine("asd");

        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                socket = _socket.EndAccept(asyncResult);
                if (_players.Count > 2 || _gameStarted)
                {
                    socket.Send(GetAsciiBytes("Sorry we have 5 players already"));
                    return;
                }
                socket.Send(GetAsciiBytes("CONNECT"));
                Console.WriteLine("Connected new socket");
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
                _socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), socket);
            }
            catch
            {
                RemovePlayer(socket);
                socket.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            int received;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                current.Close();
                RemovePlayer(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuffer = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuffer, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuffer);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

            if (_players.Count > 4)
            {
                current.Send(GetAsciiBytes("Sorry we have 5 players already"));
                current.Close();
                current.Dispose();
            }
            else if (text.Length < 7 || text.Substring(0, 5) != "LOGIN" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.Substring(6, 2)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
                current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
            }
            else
            {
                current.Send(GetAsciiBytes("OK"));
                _players.Add(new Player(current));
                Console.WriteLine("Player OK");
            }
        }

        private static void Round()
        {
            StartRound();
            while (_playersInRound.Count > 1 && _turnCards.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var player in _playersInRound)
                {
                    if (player.IsEliminated)
                    {

                    }
                    if (player.SkipTurn)
                    {
                        player.SkipTurn = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var card = GetRandomCard();
                    player.Cards.Add(card);
                    player.Socket.Send(GetAsciiBytes($"YOUR MOVE {card.Name}"));
                    var playerCardsNames = player.Cards.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
                    if (player.HaveCountessAndKingOrPrince)
                    { 
                        while(true)
                        {
                            player.Socket.Receive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        }
                    }
                    var splittedMessage = GetStringFromBytes(_buffer).Split(new char[0]);
                    var choosenPlayer = Int32.Parse(splittedMessage[2] ?? "0");
                    var choosenSecondCard = splittedMessage[3] ?? "";
                    var playedCard = player.Cards.Where(x => x.Name.ToString() == splittedMessage[1]).First();
                    player.Cards.Where(x => x.Name == playedCard.Name).FirstOrDefault().Action(player, _playersInRound.Where(x => x.Id == choosenPlayer).FirstOrDefault(), choosenSecondCard);
                    //Array.Clear(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                    RemoveEliminatedPlayers();
                }
            }
        }
        private static void StartRound()
        {
            MixPlayers();
            LoadCards();
            GiveStartingCardsToPlayers();
            foreach (var player in _playersInRound)
            {
                player.Socket.Send(GetAsciiBytes($"START {player.Id.ToString()} {player.Cards[0]}"));
            }
        }

        private static void MixPlayers()
        {
            var ids = _ids.ToList();
            var random = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var randomListIndex = random.Next(ids.Count);
                _playersInRound[i].Id = ids[randomListIndex];
                ids.RemoveAt(randomListIndex);
            }
            _playersInRound.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        }

        private static void RemovePlayer(Socket socket)
        {
            _players.Remove(_players.Where(x => x.Socket == socket).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        private static List<AbstractCard> LoadCards()
        {
            var allCards = new List<AbstractCard>();
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardName)).Cast<CardName>().ToArray();
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(CardAmount), value.ToString()); i++)
                {
                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case CardName.Baron:
                            allCards.Add(new BaronCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Countess:
                            allCards.Add(new CountessCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Guard:
                            allCards.Add(new GuardCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Handmaiden:
                            allCards.Add(new HandmaidenCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.King:
                            allCards.Add(new KingCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Priest:
                            allCards.Add(new PriestCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Prince:
                            allCards.Add(new PrinceCard());
                            break;
                        case CardName.Princess:
                            allCards.Add(new PrincessCard());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return allCards;
        }

        private static AbstractCard GetRandomCard()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var randomIndex = random.Next(_turnCards.Count);
            var randomCard = _turnCards[randomIndex];
            _turnCards.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            return randomCard;
        }

        private static void GiveStartingCardsToPlayers()
        {
            foreach (var player in _playersInRound)
            {
                player.Cards.Add(GetRandomCard());
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveEliminatedPlayers()
        {
            Predicate<Player> eliminated = (Player player) => { return player.IsEliminated == true; };
            _playersInRound.RemoveAll(eliminated);
            _players.ForEach(x => x.ClearElimination());
        }

        private static byte[] GetAsciiBytes(string text)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        }

        private static string GetStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly stackoverflow site says that it looks like my post is mostly code but i have described everything above so sorry for this pointless text here.

Comment: The net library does not allow Asynchronous reads and Synchronous Writes. I cannot translate to English you exception.  Please post in English.

Comment: @jdweng is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You have to use the Asynchronous send method.  See the msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Answer (score 0):

you have created the static buffer array which is giving you out stackoverflow exception this is because multiple clients requesting at the same time. they used this static buffer for both. it is not a good in development creating static buffer.
you have to comes up with some new login like this.

```
 public class SocketPacketforROD
{
    public System.Net.Sockets.Socket CurrentSocket;

    //test
    public int last_buffer_read = 0;
    public int last_socket_payload_size = 0;

    public byte[] Data = null; // new byte[Server.bufferLength];

    public SocketPacketforROD_State m_state = SocketPacketforROD_State.socket_state_payload_size;

    public void allocate(int bytes)
    {
        // socket_buffer_length = bytes;
        Data = new byte[bytes];
    }
}
```

**Used this socket object class in your onreceiveddata method**

```
 string Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(socketData.Data);
                        Logger.WriteLog("Message Received length : " + Data.Length + " from: " + socketData.CurrentSocket.RemoteEndPoint, LogLevel.GENERALLOG);

                        socketData.m_state = SocketPacketforROD_State.socket_state_payload_size;
```

**Setup Receive callback**

```
  private void SetupReceiveCallback(Socket objClientSocket)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(OnRecievedData);
            SocketPacketforROD theSocPkt = new SocketPacketforROD();
            theSocPkt.last_socket_payload_size = 4;
            theSocPkt.allocate(4);
            theSocPkt.CurrentSocket = objClientSocket;
            Logger.WriteLog("After New Socket buffer Length : " + theSocPkt.Data.Length, LogLevel.GENERALLOG);
            objClientSocket.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.Data, 0, theSocPkt.Data.Length, SocketFlags.None, recieveData, theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException MemEXP)
        {
            Logger.WriteException(MemEXP);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Logger.WriteException(E);
        }
    }
```